# How to read all csv files from web page in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I'm trying to read all .csv files from https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports to a data frame.

My code so far:

```
url = 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports'
x = requests.get(url).text
filenames = re.findall('[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{4}.csv', x)
frame = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(url + y) for y in filenames)
```

Maybe somebody can help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the URL to

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/'
```

and it should work. This gives you access to the raw csv file and not to a page the csv is on.

Edit:
Just noticed that you need your old url to get the filenames:

```
url_raw = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/'
url = 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports'
x = requests.get(url).text
filenames = re.findall('[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{4}.csv', x)
frame = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(url_raw + y) for y in filenames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to run with the following code

> frame = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f'{url}/{y}') for y in filenames)

Comment: Thank you ;) I'll try it :D

Answer (score 0):

Just as an additional note, you might not get the expected behaviour from pd.concat as the csv files in the url given are inconsistent column-wise (see examples below). You might want to rename or strip some of the columns before concat.

```
01-27-2020.csv
Province/State,Country/Region,Last Update,Confirmed,Deaths,Recovered
03-01-2020.csv
Province/State,Country/Region,Last Update,Confirmed,Deaths,Recovered,Latitude,Longitude
04-26-2020.csv
FIPS,Admin2,Province_State,Country_Region,Last_Update,Lat,Long_,Confirmed,Deaths,Recovered,Active,Combined_Key
06-28-2020.csv
FIPS,Admin2,Province_State,Country_Region,Last_Update,Lat,Long_,Confirmed,Deaths,Recovered,Active,Combined_Key,Incidence_Rate,Case-Fatality_Ratio
```